# How to get the current value of LC_CTYPE etc. in Bash?

Tags: bash, locale

Basically, how to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14818031/96588) in Bash? Parsing the output of `locale` - `declare "$(locale | grep ^LC_CTYPE | tr --delete '"')"` - seems yucky, as it involves four separate commands. Remember, just because `locale` prints values for most or all variables doesn't mean those variables are actually set! For example, `locale` prints `LC_CTYPE="en_NZ.UTF-8"` (among other lines) on my machine, but `echo "$LC_CTYPE"` prints nothing.

Comment: In a subshell, `eval` the output of `locale` and then see `$LC_CTYPE`?  I'm not posting this as an answer because I have not determined that doing this is always safe.

Comment: I don't really want to set the variables if I can avoid it.

Comment: That's why I mentioned possibly doing it in a subshell.

Comment: What do you actually want though, the value of the `$LC_CTYPE` variable or the value returned by `locale`? If the latter, is `locale | grep -Po 'LC_CTYPE="\K[^"]+'` simple enough or do you need something more portable that doesn't require GNU `grep`? Do you want the variable to be set after your command?

Comment: After further investigation the question I *actually* want answered is [How to determine which Compose file is in use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/757645/3645) - getting `LC_CTYPE` showed that its value was strangely not relevant to the underlying question. I'll leave this question here though, since I still think it's useful.

Comment: Ah, should this be closed then?

Comment: Nah, I feel like the `locale` command (or something else) should just have some trivial way to get the *value* of a specific locale configuration, rather than having to jump through hoops with complex `grep`s or multiple commands. Until that's the case this question could still use a good answer.

Comment: OK, then can you clarify if you want the `LC_CTYPE` variable to be set after whatever command or if you just want to see the value? Any reason yo don't just do `. <(locale | grep '^LC_CTYPE=')` for example? Why do you need `declare`?

Comment: Source the locale line? I didn't know that was a thing. I used `declare` because I remember it being safer than `eval`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148810/discussion-between-terdon-and-l0b0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to man [`locale`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locale.1.html) the value of `LC_CTYPE` being enclosed in double quotes signifies it's an "implied value":

> Values for variables set in the environment are printed without
> double quotes, implied values are printed with double quotes.

which means that `LC_CTYPE` is not set and `locale` will print the "implied" value which, [if I understand correctly](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html), will be the value of `LC_ALL` or, if that's not set either, the value of `LANG`:

> For glibc, first (regardless of category), the environment variable LC_ALL is inspected,
> next the environment variable with the same name as the category, and finally the environment variable LANG. The first
> existing environment variable is used

So `locale` will use the first value it finds, in this order: `LC_ALL`, then `LC_CTYPE` and then `LANG`
Note that `LC_ALL` takes precedence if set, so even if `LC_CTYPE` was set too (maybe to a different locale) `locale` will report the value of `LC_ALL` for `LC_CTYPE`.

In conclusion, to get the value of `LC_CTYPE` that is currently being used by `locale` you could run something like

```
echo ${LC_ALL:-${LC_CTYPE:-$LANG}}
```

---

Initially I had thought the goal was to get the actual value of `LC_CTYPE` if set and only if it's not set, fall back to what `locale` uses, in which case the first two variables have to be swapped:

```
echo ${LC_CTYPE:-${LC_ALL:-$LANG}}
```

Comment: "if I understand correctly, will be the value of LC_ALL or, if that's not set either, the value of LANG." Do you have a reference for that? If that's really the case your solution is the simplest.

Comment: That reads like the precedence is `LC_ALL` > all other `LC_*` variables > `LANG`. So it should be `${LC_ALL:-${LC_CTYPE:-$LANG}}`?

Comment: @l0b0 - ok, my bad, I understand now what you meant (I guess my ADHD got the best of me...) I've edited the post.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming evaluating the output of `locale` is safe (we assume that `locale` is not a shell function, alias, or other non-standard utility):

```bash
(eval "$(locale)" && printf '%s\n' "$LC_CTYPE")
```

This sets all the `LC_` and associated variables in the subshell environment and outputs the value of the `LC_CTYPE` variable. Performing the `eval` inside the subshell avoids polluting the parent environment with the `LC_` variables.

Example run on my OpenBSD system where I only ever set `LANG=C.UTF-8`:

```bash
$ (eval "$(locale)" && printf '%s\n' "$LC_CTYPE")
C.UTF-8
```

If you like to set (and export) the `LC_CTYPE` variable to the value reported by `locale` without setting *other* variables:

```bash
$ export LC_CTYPE="$(eval "$(locale)" && printf '%s\n' "$LC_CTYPE")"
$ printf '%s\n' "$LC_CTYPE"
C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to parse the output of `locale` and then set the variable, you can just source it directly like this:

```
. <(locale | grep '^LC_CTYPE=')
```

That selects only the `LC_TYPE` line:

```
$ locale | grep '^LC_CTYPE='
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

And then you source that, using the `.` builtin, into the current shell:

```
$ echo $LC_CTYPE 

$ . <(locale | grep '^LC_CTYPE=')
$ echo "$LC_CTYPE"
en_US.UTF-8
```

Note that this requires a shell that supports [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), such as `bash` or `zsh` or `ksh` and others. If you are not using such a shell, you might need to do something more complicated like

```
locale | grep '^LC_CTYPE=' > file && . ./file
```

Comment: The value could just be output, stripping the assignment, and without the need to write it into a file: `locale | sed -n '/LC_CTYPE/{s/^LC_CTYPE=//;p}'`.

Comment: @Vilinkameni you mean `LC_CTYPE=$(locale | sed -n '/LC_CTYPE/{s/^LC_CTYPE=//;p}')`? That won't work, you need to remove the quotes else you get an error (`setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale ("en_US.UTF-8")`). In any case, you wouldn't use something that complicated, even if you had to use `sed`, you could do `locale | sed -n 's/^LC_CTYPE=//p'`.

Comment: Of course. If setting the variable is intended, the whole thing can be piped through `tr -d '"'`. Somehow I like this answer better than using `eval` though.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external commands, except for `locale`:

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ "${line}" =~ ^LC_CTYPE= ]] && {
        export LC_CTYPE="${line#*=}"
        break
    }
done < <(locale)
```

Comment: You don't want `LC_CTYPE*`, the OP needs to match just `LC_CTYPE` and nothing else, so you should even change the regex to `^LC_CTYPE=` to avoid matching a variable named `LC_CTYPE2` or whatever. Also, you're not setting te variable and I think the OP wants that. Can you explain the benefit of this? It is a tiny bit faster than `locale | grep -m1  '^LC_TYPE'`, but the difference is negligible (average 0.00251495 seconds for the shel loop vs 0.00286379 for grep over 300 repetitions).

Comment: The only benefit I saw was not using external commands. However, I did not take into account the performance difference.