# How to determine which Compose file is in use?

Tags: linux, locale, nixos

My locale is set to "en_NZ.UTF-8". There is no directory by that name listed by `ls "$(nix eval -f '<nixpkgs>' --raw xorg.libX11)/share/X11/locale/"`, and X applications don't even try to [read compose keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164900/3645) from that directory:

```
❯ strace xterm -e true 2>&1 | grep -i "$(nix eval -f '<nixpkgs>' --raw xorg.libX11)/share/X11/locale/en_"
access("/nix/store/z5dlm8l0yzh4d3l2370lb1m2hfmcdfiy-libX11-1.8.6/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/XLC_LOCALE", R_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/nix/store/z5dlm8l0yzh4d3l2370lb1m2hfmcdfiy-libX11-1.8.6/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/XLC_LOCALE", O_RDONLY) = 4
access("/nix/store/z5dlm8l0yzh4d3l2370lb1m2hfmcdfiy-libX11-1.8.6/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose", R_OK) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/nix/store/z5dlm8l0yzh4d3l2370lb1m2hfmcdfiy-libX11-1.8.6/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=460228, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/nix/store/z5dlm8l0yzh4d3l2370lb1m2hfmcdfiy-libX11-1.8.6/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=460228, ...}, 0) = 0
```

So what is determining that the compose keys should come from the "en_*US*.UTF-8" locale?